# How do I create a "link" to move from one Activity to another?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a three-page/Activity setup/configuration piece to my app.

I want to have two "links" at the bottom of the first Activity the user can utilize to navigate to one of the other Activities that appear like hyperlinks. Is this considered bad form? If not, how to do it?

Comment: they appear like hyperlinks, but wat exactly are they, button, textview etc?

Comment: I would also add that as a user I hate it when click-able things are along the very bottom of the screen. If you're going to put it at the bottom make sure there is some margin underneath it. There are many devices with soft system keys that are directly beneath the edge of the touch screen. It is easy to hit them when aiming for something that is alignParentBottom in an activity, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably bad form, but design is an art and it depends on what you're going for. Not knowing anything, I'd recommend a standard button for this.

Comment: I agree. You really should consider following the style standards set out by Google. Android users will not be expecting hyperlink style "buttons" in a native app. If you REALLY want to do it this way, I would suggest subclassing `Button`, but I think its bad form.